# Error while passing file in android studio

Tags: java, python, android-studio, file, chaquopy

I'm trying to pass a file from java to python. To load the file I'm using Picasso, since I to get width and height. But when I call the same file to pass it to python, it gives me an error. This is the java code:

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.f21).into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                        imageString = getStringImage(bitmap);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        PyObject pyo = py.getModule("Heat");
                        PyObject obj = pyo.callAttr("Python", bitmap, lrange, urange);
                        String str = obj.toString();
                        byte data[] = android.util.Base64.decode(str, Base64.DEFAULT);

                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                        iv2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
            at <python>Heat.Python(Heat.py:9)  
            at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:209)
```

But when I try to load the image from drawable, it is not successfully passed onto the python script. It does not show me any error, but shows this message:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 129 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

How can I pass the image from java to python script.

My python code is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image


def Python(croppedImage,lowerRange, upperRange):
    mask_yellow = cv2.inRange(croppedImage,lowerRange,upperRange)
    dilatation_type = cv2.MORPH_RECT

hMin = 1
sMin = 0
vMin = 0

hMax = 107
sMax = 38
vMax = 265

output = image
wait_time = 30
lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])
upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])
print(lower,upper)

 hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

-----------------------------This is just a part of code---------------------------------
```

Comment: Python OpenCV functions won't accept Android Bitmap objects, or Android drawable IDs. So if you did manage to "load the image from drawable", you must have used some other method. Please edit your question to explain what that method was.

Comment: Also, as with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910312), there seems to be some confusion when passing arguments to Python. You're passing a width and height, but the Python function is treating them as a lower and upper range.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. On editing my code, I found that drawable image was set only in imageview and was not carried onto the python script. I guess the only was to pass the image from java to python is by using URI. In addition to that, is there any way to get the upperrange and lowerrange of any image without specifying it.

Comment: I can't answer that because you haven't explained what the range means or why you're using it. But for passing the image, the easiest way is to encode it as a PNG or JPG file and then pass it as a byte array. See [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/303#issuecomment-637596980) for an example.

Comment: The lower and upper range are basically HSV limit for the image. I've updated the python script. Also I really appreciate the help.

Comment: OK, I can help if you still have difficulty with passing the file, but the image processing sounds like a separate issue which I don't know much about, so you'd better ask a separate question for that, and tag it with "opencv".

Comment: Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it :D